# itertools.groupby количество элементов в группе

Tags: python

Мне нужно посчитать количество одинаковых подряд идущих строк. Для этого я использую **itertools.groupby**.

**Вопрос:** как определить количество элементов в группе? len(grop) не работает. Есть ли у объекта какое нибудь свойство, типа size()?

```
data = (line.rstrip() for line in sys.stdin)
for key, group in groupby(data):
   print(data.size())
```

Comment: похожий вопрос: [Length of a finite generator](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18014437/4279)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import itertools
qwe = 'qwe2', 'qwe2', 'qwe1', 'qwe2'
for key, group in itertools.groupby(qwe):
    li = list(group)
    print('key {} has len {}: {}'.format(key, len(li), li))
```

out:

```
key qwe2 has len 2: ['qwe2', 'qwe2']
key qwe1 has len 1: ['qwe1']
key qwe2 has len 1: ['qwe2']
```

Comment: Если `group` может быть очень большой (мы не знаем что в stdin скармливается), то можно `sum(1 for _ in group)` использовать (предполагая что ничто кроме числа нас не интересует). `sum(..)` может быть медленнее чем `len(list(group))`, но позволяет хоть терабайты данных скармливать.